# how get new data from database in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

My projct is a note app where you can can add notes and delete notes. I want to get data from the database and show it but I have to delete note twice, add note or reload page to show the new data.

**notesList.jsx**
this is my main component
i send getNotes() to another component for i can get new datas

```
const NotesList = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  const getNotes = async () => {
    const getNoteInformation = {
      email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
    };
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:9000/api/note/get",
      getNoteInformation
    );
    try {
      setNotes(response.data.data);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const handleAddNote = async (tasktext) => {
    const addNoteInformation = {
      email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
      taskText: tasktext,
      date: moment(new Date()).locale("fa").format("YYYY/MM/DD").toString(),
    };

    if (addNoteInformation.email && addNoteInformation.taskText) {
      try {
        await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:9000/api/note/add",
          addNoteInformation
        );
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteNote = async (id) => {
    const deletedInformaion = {
      email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
      noteId: id,
    };

    if (deletedInformaion.email && deletedInformaion.noteId) {
      await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:9000/api/note/deleted",
        deletedInformaion
      );
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      getNotes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {notes
            .filter((notes) => notes != null)
            .map((notes, index) => (
              <Note
                key={index}
                text={notes.text}
                date={notes.date}
                id={notes._id}
                deletenote={handleDeleteNote}
                getnote={getNotes}
              />
            ))}
          <AddNote getnote={getNotes} addnote={handleAddNote} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**note.jsx**

```
const Note = (props) => {
  const handleDeleteNote =  () => {
    props.deletenote(props.id);
    props.getnote();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 p-4">
        <div className="note d-flex flex-column">
          <span className="note-top overflow-auto m-2 ps-2">{props.text}</span>
          <div className="note-bottom d-flex justify-content-between flex-row-reverse mt-auto">
            <small>{props.date}</small>
            <MdDelete
              onClick={handleDeleteNote}
              className="delete-icon"
              size="1.3rem"
              color="#bb86fc"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**addNote.jsx**

```
const AddNote = (props) => {
  let addNoteText = useRef();

  const handleAddNote = async () => {
    props.addnote(addNoteText.current.value);
    props.getnote();
    addNoteText.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 p-4">
      <div className="add-note-box d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div className="top-box">
          <textarea
            placeholder="یادداشت خود را وارد کنید ......"
            class="form-control"
            rows={7}
            ref={addNoteText}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <BsFillPlusCircleFill
          onClick={handleAddNote}
          className="plus-icon"
          size="1.3rem"
          color="#bb86fc"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't update state after sending the respective `add` and `delete` request, that's why you need to refresh to get the updated data. This is the fix:

```
  const handleAddNote = async (tasktext) => {
    const addNoteInformation = {
      email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
      taskText: tasktext,
      date: moment(new Date()).locale("fa").format("YYYY/MM/DD").toString(),
    };

    if (addNoteInformation.email && addNoteInformation.taskText) {
      try {
        await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:9000/api/note/add",
          addNoteInformation
        );
     
        setNotes([...notes, addNoteInformation]); // update state using spread operator and put the new one to the end
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteNote = async (id) => {
    const deletedInformaion = {
      email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
      noteId: id,
    };

    if (deletedInformaion.email && deletedInformaion.noteId) {
      await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:9000/api/note/deleted",
        deletedInformaion
      );
      
      setNotes(notes.filter(note => note.id !== id)) // update state using filter function
    }
  };
```

Alternativelly, when adding notes, you can update state using the `response object` from your request, since the `id` of newly created note maybe generated by your database. It dependes on the actual response object from the axios request:

```
const response = await axios.post();
setNotes([...notes, response.data]);
```